# Can't get my f# to work when using 2 for loops

Tags: loops, for-loop, f#

Hey i'm trying to make an function that get's an sum of something. But it seems like my creation dosen't work and gives me errors inside my text editor. Here is the code

```
let myFunction (n:int):int =
    let mutable sum = 0
    for i = 0 to n+2 do
    for j = i-1 to n+1 do

        sum<- sum + 1 

    sum
```

it gives me this error around the for loops

"This expression was expected to have type
    'int'
but here has type
    'unit'"

Comment: You're not returning the sum value anywhere, just assigning it.

Comment: How would it look like? I'm new to f# and coding in general

Comment: The last expression of the function is its return value. So add a line reading `sum` at the end of your function, and then you will be returning the sum that you calculated.

Comment: BTW, I assume your actual code had indentation, and that the indentation was lost when you pasted it into the Stack Overflow question box. When asking questions about F#, where indentation is significant, it helps to take a minute to make sure that the indentation has come through correctly in your question. When you're typing a question, there's a handy preview below the question box, which can help you determine whether you've gotten the indentation correct.

Comment: Yeah I fixed the indentation in my question, but still when I use sum as my return value it still gives me the same error

Comment: Your indentation doesn't look quite right yet: the second `for` loop should be indented inside the first one.

Comment: ahhh correct thank you very much for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've understood your `myFunction` logic correctly, this is what it should look like:

```
let myFunction (n:int):int =
    let mutable sum = 0
    for i = 0 to n+2 do
        for j = i-1 to n+1 do
            sum <- sum + 1
    sum
```

Note two things that were different from your original code:

1. The second `for` loop is indented to be placed "inside" the first one, and
2. There's a `sum` line at the end: the last expression of the function is its return value. So by adding a line reading `sum` at the end of the function, you cause it to return the sum that you calculated.